# What does ViewData!ReturnUrl = returnUrl mean/do in vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

In my out of the box ASP.Net MVC Web App, This login function has the line

```
ViewData!ReturnUrl = returnUrl
```

What does that syntax do? I have never seen Something!Somthing before

```
<AllowAnonymous>
Public Function Login(returnUrl As String) As ActionResult
    ViewData!ReturnUrl = returnUrl

    Return View()
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an operator for accessing dictionaries - take a look here for documentation of it:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxda45fy.aspx